# NSPredicate creation with CoreData for an equal object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a strong pointer with the name "sensor" to an object of the class "SensorDB".

I tried to create a NSFetchedResultController so that my UIViewController gets notified, if something changes inside the "sensor" object.

To get the desired object into my NSFetchedResultController, I created following NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", self.sensor];
```

The goal is, that I have just one object in the NSFetchedResultController and get notifications about any updates, so that I can update my GUI.

But if I run my application, the app crashes when I try to alloc and init the NSFetchedResultController.

Here's my NSFetchedResultController code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerSensor
{
    if (_fetchedResultsControllerSensor != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsControllerSensor;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SensorDB" inManagedObjectContext:dbHandler.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", self.sensor];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:dbHandler.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"SensorCache"];
    self.fetchedResultsControllerSensor = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsControllerSensor.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsControllerSensor;
}
```

Thank you for your help or another/better approach

Linard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought, that I don't need a sort descriptor, because I've just one result object, but it looks like that the initialization of a NSFetchedResultController crashes, if there isn't at least one NSSortDescriptor.

That's now my NSPredicate and NSSortDescriptor:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(SELF = %@)", self.sensor];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```